# How to extract characters and numeric values from a given string?

Tags: python, string

I have the following strings:

```
'10000 ABC = 1 DEF'
'1 AM = 0,30$'
'3500 ABC = 1 GTY'
'1000 HUYT=1ABC'
'1 MONET Data = 1 ABC'
```

I want to find a flexible way to extract numeric and string values from left and right sides of `=`. I do not know all possible string values. Therefore I cannot pre-define them. The only thing that I know is that left and right sides are divided by `=`.

The goal is to get this result for the above-given example:

`String-pairs`:

```
ABC-DEF
AM-$
ABC-GTY
HUYT-ABC
MONET Data-ABC
```

`Numeric-pairs`:

```
10000-1
1-0.30
3500-1
1000-1
1-1
```

I was trying to use `.lstrip('...')` and `rstrip("...")`, but it does not give me the expected result.

Comment: show us your code? It looks like you need regex.

Comment: Should `'1 MONET Data = 1 ABC'` result in `'MONET Data-ABC'` and not `'MONETData-ABC'` when getting the string pair?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: there should a space between MONET and Data.

Comment: Where is your code?  This problem is riddled with nasty egde cases, and seeing your attempt would make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the unwanted characters and replace the `=` with a `-`.

```
import re

str = ['10000 ABC = 1 DEF',
    '1 AM = 0,30$',
    '3500 ABC = 1 GTY',
    '1000 HUYT=1ABC',
    '1 MONET Data = 1 ABC']

String_pairs = []
Numeric_pairs = []

for s in str:
    String_pairs.append (re.sub(r'\s*=\s*','-', re.sub(r'\s*\d+(,\d+)?\s*','', s)))
    Numeric_pairs.append (re.sub(r'\s*=\s*','-', re.sub(r'\s*[^\d,=]+\s*','', s)))

print String_pairs
print Numeric_pairs
```

Result:

```
['ABC-DEF', 'AM-$', 'ABC-GTY', 'HUYT-ABC', 'MONET Data-ABC']
['10000-1', '1-0,30', '3500-1', '1000-1', '1-1']
```

or a more cooler list comprehension (with the same result):

```
String_pairs = [re.sub(r'\s*=\s*','-', re.sub(r'\s*\d+(,\d+)?\s*','', s)) for s in str]
Numeric_pairs = [re.sub(r'\s*=\s*','-', re.sub(r'\s*[^\d,=]+\s*','', s)) for s in str]
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to regex, what you could do is to loop through each string and extract the relevant characters. It could look something along the lines of the following.

```
def extract_string_pairs(source_string):
    string_pair = ''
    for c in source_string:
        if c.isalpha() or c == '$':
            string_pair += c
        elif c == '=':
            string_pair += '-'

    return string_pair

def extract_numeric_pairs(source_string):
    string_pair = ''
    for c in source_string:
        if c.isdigit():
            string_pair += c
        elif c == '.':
            string_pair += '.'
        elif c == '=':
            string_pair += '-'

    return string_pair
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

str = ['10000 ABC = 1 DEF',
       '1 AM = 0,30$',
       '3500 ABC = 1 GTY',
       '1000 HUYT=1ABC',
       '1 MONET Data = 1 ABC']


def getThePat(pat):
    for i in str:
        i = i.split("=")
        x = re.findall(pat, i[0])
        y = re.findall(pat, i[1])
        print(" ".join(x), "-", " ".join(y))


pat1 = "\$+|[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+"
pat2 = "\d+|\,+"
getThePat(pat1)
getThePat(pat2)
```

output:

```
ABC - DEF
AM - $
ABC - GTY
HUYT - ABC
MONET Data - ABC
10000 - 1
1 - 0 , 30
3500 - 1
1000 - 1
1 - 1
```